# How to add a new element in an xml which will take the value(portion) of the existing element

Tags: xslt

I wonder how to put XSLT for converting an xml as below.

**My Input xml:**

```
    <Name>
        <Dept>Static-Computers</Dept>
        <Name>SomeName</Name>
        <DateJoined>Somevalue</DateJoined>
    </Name>
```

I want to convert this input xml by adding a new element named 'DeptName' which copies the second portion of the string from Dept element.

**My expected Output:**

```
    <Name>
        <Dept>Static-Computers</Dept>
        <DeptName>Computers</DeptName>
        <Name>SomeName</Name>
        <DateJoined>Somevalue</DateJoined>
    </Name>
```

Comment: give second portion of the string

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4R):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  >
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
   
  <xsl:template match="Dept">      
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <DeptName>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '-')"/>
      </DeptName>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Raghu - glad to help! if it serves your purpose, you can accept the answer. or you can wait for other answers depending your requirements.